# Connection Refused to Django test server when run in github actions

Tags: django, docker-compose, github-actions

I have a django project that is containerized in Docker. In a separate project, I am trying to use docker compose to load my django project as a service, and then use GitHub Actions to confirm that the django server is running.

Every attempt to run `curl` to test whether the django server is running has failed, with no response. I tried running the curl command INSIDE the container, using `docker exec`, and it fails with "connection refused".

If I `docker compose build --no-cache`, then `docker compose up`, and then `curl -X GET localhost:8000/version/` locally, it works perfectly. It also works locally if I attempt to run `curl` from inside the container. It only fails in the github actions.

My docker-compose.yml file reads as follows:

```
services:
  blawx:
    build: https://github.com/Lexpedite/blawx.git#v1.3.40-alpha
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - 8000
    volumes:
      - ./blawx/fixtures:/app/blawx/blawx/fixtures/nrcan-map
```

My github actions file looks like this:

```
jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build and run the Docker Images from docker-compose.yaml
      run: docker compose up -d
    - name: Show Running Containers
      run: docker ps
    - name: Check Blawx Heartbeat
      run: |
        docker exec -t nrcan-map-blawx-1 curl --retry 5 -X GET "localhost:8000/"
    - name: Shut Down Docker Containers
      run: docker compose down
```

The log shows the build action failing on Check Blawx Heartbeat, with error code 7, "connection refused."

When I tried running `curl` inside the host instead of the container, I got error code 52, "empty response."

If I am getting connection refused from inside the Docker container, that suggests to me that the problem is a Django security configuration issue. For Django, allowed hosts is set to ["*"] in the settings.

I suspect that there is some combination of using docker compose and django and github actions that isn't playing nicely, but I haven't been able to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was being caused by the curl test being run too quickly - after the docker container was run, but before it was able to respond to requests.

The solution was to add the following before the `curl` step.

```
  - name: Wait
    run: sleep 10s
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to  IPv6 support of Docker, can you try passing `-4` or `--ipv4` option to curl?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).